# how can I solve this error: tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "menu" command: application has been destroyed?

Tags: python, tkinter

Full error description:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Технології\Лабораторки\ЛР 25\ЛР25.py", line 484, in 
> app = App()
> File "C:\Технології\Лабораторки\ЛР 25\ЛР25.py", line 49, in **init**
> self.createMainMenu()
> File "C:\Технології\Лабораторки\ЛР 25\ЛР25.py", line 63, in createMainMenu
> thememenu = tk.Menu(self.submenus[1], bg = "black", selectcolor = "white", fg = "white", activebackground = "white", activeforeground = "black", tearoff = 0)
> File "C:\Users\bredu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 3343, in **init**
> Widget.**init**(self, master, 'menu', cnf, kw)
> File "C:\Users\bredu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 2628, in **init**
> self.tk.call(
> _tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "menu" command: application has been destroyed

My app:
[image: App]

[image: App]

I'm trying to make a menu.

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import webbrowser

class App(tk.Tk):
    
    topbuttons = None
    service = None
    openAnimeListButton = None
    childWindow = None
    hint = None
    frames = None
    mainmenu = None
    submenus = []
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Мои самые любимые аниме-тайтлы")
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_closing)
        self.geometry("1200x680")
        self.resizable(False, False)
        self["background"] = "black"
        self.frames = [tk.Frame(self), tk.LabelFrame(self, text = "Сколько вам лет?", font = "Arial 13", bg = "black", fg = "white")]
        bt1 = tk.Button(self.frames[0], text = "Сёнэн", height = 2, width = 14, bg = "black", fg = "white",\
            font = "Arial 13", relief = "groove", overrelief = "sunken")
        bt2 = tk.Button(self.frames[0], text = "Комедия", height = 2, width = 14, bg = "black", fg = "white",\
            font = "Arial 13", relief = "groove", overrelief = "sunken")
        bt3 = tk.Button(self.frames[0], text = "Психология", height = 2, width = 14, bg = "black", fg = "white",\
            font = "Arial 13", relief = "groove", overrelief = "sunken")
        bt4 = tk.Button(self.frames[0], text = "Повседневность", height = 2, width = 16, bg = "black", fg = "white",\
            font = "Arial 13", relief = "groove", overrelief = "sunken")
        bt5 = tk.Button(self.frames[0], text = "Триллер", height = 2, width = 14, bg = "black", fg = "white",\
            font = "Arial 13", relief = "groove", overrelief = "sunken")
        self.topbuttons = [bt1, bt2, bt3, bt4, bt5]
        self.frames[0].pack()
        for x in self.topbuttons:
            x.pack(side="left")
        
        self.openAnimeListButton = tk.Button(self, text = "Открыть список\nпросмотренных мною аниме", height = 2, width = 26, bg = "black", fg = "white",\
            font = "Arial 13", relief = "groove", overrelief = "sunken")
        self.openAnimeListButton.place(x = 956, y = 628)
        
        self.service = Service(self)

        self.hint = tk.Label(self, text = "Ctrl+Double click the left mouse\nbutton - close app.\nCtrl+Shift+R - restart app.\nCtrl+o - open child window.", justify = "left", bg = "black", fg = "white", font = "Arial 18", cursor="hand2")
        self.hint.place(x = 1, y = 565)

        self.createMainMenu()

    def createMainMenu(self):
        self.mainmenu = tk.Menu(self)
        self.config(menu=self.mainmenu)
        self.mainmenu.add_command(label="Аниме")
        animemenu = tk.Menu(self.mainmenu, bg = "black", fg = "white", activebackground = "white", activeforeground = "black", tearoff = 0)
        viewmenu = tk.Menu(self.mainmenu, bg = "black", fg = "white", activebackground = "white", activeforeground = "black", tearoff = 0)
        docmenu = tk.Menu(self.mainmenu, bg = "black", fg = "white", activebackground = "white", activeforeground = "black", tearoff = 0)
        self.submenus.append(animemenu)
        self.submenus.append(viewmenu)
        self.submenus.append(docmenu)
        
        self.mainmenu.add_cascade(label = "Вид", menu = self.submenus[1])
        thememenu = tk.Menu(self.submenus[1], bg = "black", selectcolor = "white", fg = "white", activebackground = "white", activeforeground = "black", tearoff = 0) #Here's an error
        self.submenus.append(thememenu)
        optionVar = tk.BooleanVar()
        optionVar.set(0)
        self.submenus[3].add_radiobutton(label = "Тёмная", value=0, variable=optionVar, command = self.service.makeBlackTheme)
        self.submenus[3].add_radiobutton(label = "Светлая", value=1, variable=optionVar, command = self.service.makeLightTheme)
        self.submenus[1].add_cascade(label = "Тема", menu = self.submenus[3])
        
        self.mainmenu.add_cascade(label = "Справка", menu = self.submenus[2])
        self.submenus[2].add_command(label = "О приложении", command = self.service.showInfoAboutApp)
        self.submenus[2].add_command(label = "Контакт. данные разраба", command = self.service.showContact)

    def startApp(self):
        print("Начало программы.")
        self.mainloop()
        print("Конец программы.")
        
    def on_closing(self):
        if messagebox.askokcancel("Выход из приложения", "Хотите выйти из приложения?"):
            global running
            running = False
            self.delObject()

    def delObject(self):
        for x in self.topbuttons:
            del x
        del self.service
        del self.openAnimeListButton
        if self.childWindow != None: del self.childWindow
        del self.hint
        for x in self.frames:
            del x
        for x in self.submenus:
            del x
        del self.mainmenu
        self.destroy()

class Service():
    root = None
    showedElementsByClickingButtom = {}
    activeElements = None
    checker = False
    links = {}
    activeLinks = None
    clickedButton = None
    printedAge = None
    constantAge = None
    checkbutton = None
    myTextField = None
    mySendAgeButton = None
    ageLabel = None
    myRadioButtons = None
    listOfAnimesElement = None
    listOfAnimes = None
    listOfAnimes_var = None
    currentButtonIndex = 0
    wasCurrentButtonIndexLastChangedAfterTab = False
    windowInfoAboutApp = None
    windowContactInfo = None
    lbContactInfoOrInAboutApp = None

    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        
        for btn in self.root.topbuttons:
            btn.config(command = lambda text = btn["text"]: self.printInfoAboutAnime(text))
            btn.bind("<Enter>", lambda event, bt = btn: self.showPage(event, bt))

        self.root.bind('<Control-Double-Button-1>', self.exitWin)
        self.root.bind('<Control-Shift-R>', self.restartApp)
        self.root.bind('<Control-o>', self.openChildWindow)
        self.root.openAnimeListButton.bind('<Button-3>', lambda event, btn = self.root.openAnimeListButton: self.changeStyleOfButton(event, btn))
        self.root.openAnimeListButton.bind('<Button-1>', self.openChildWindow)

    def exitWin(self, event):
        self.root.on_closing()

    def restartApp(self, event):
        print("Перезапуск программы.")
        self.delObject()
        self.root.delObject()

    def delObject(self):
        allGenres = list(self.showedElementsByClickingButtom.keys())
        if allGenres != None:
            for x in allGenres:
                del self.showedElementsByClickingButtom[x]

    def makeBlackTheme(self):
        print("Black")

    def makeLightTheme(self):
        print("Light")

    def changeStyleOfButton(self, event, btn):
        btn.config(bg = "green", fg = "red", activebackground = "black", activeforeground = "green")
    
    def showPage(self, event, btn):
        btn.invoke()

    def showInfoAboutApp(self):
        if self.windowInfoAboutApp != None:
            self.windowInfoAboutApp.destroy()
        if self.windowContactInfo != None:
            self.windowContactInfo.destroy()
        if self.root.childWindow != None:
            self.root.childWindow.destroy()
        self.windowInfoAboutApp = tk.Toplevel(self.root, highlightthickness = 0, bd = 0)
        self.windowInfoAboutApp.title("Информация о приложении")
        self.windowInfoAboutApp.resizable(False, False)
        self.windowInfoAboutApp["background"] = "black"
        self.windowInfoAboutApp.geometry("450x215+600+300")
        self.lbContactInfoOrInAboutApp = tk.Label(self.windowInfoAboutApp, justify = "left", text = "Данное приложение было создано с целью \nпоказать мои навыки разработки графического \nинтерфейса пользователя, используя объектно-\nориентированный подход. В приложении вы \nсможете увидеть по два моих самых любимых \nаниме из 5 самых любимых жанров, список \nпросмотренных аниме, а также вы сможете \nпройти небольшой опросик) \nЖелаю удачи!;)", bg = "black", fg = "white", font = "Arial 14")
        self.lbContactInfoOrInAboutApp.place(x = 1, y = 1)

    def showContact(self):
        if self.windowInfoAboutApp != None:
            self.windowInfoAboutApp.destroy()
        if self.windowContactInfo != None:
            self.windowContactInfo.destroy()
        if self.root.childWindow != None:
            self.root.childWindow.destroy()
        self.windowContactInfo = tk.Toplevel(self.root, highlightthickness = 0, bd = 0)
        self.windowContactInfo.title("Контактная информация разработчика")
        self.windowContactInfo.resizable(False, False)
        self.windowContactInfo["background"] = "black"
        self.windowContactInfo.geometry("275x120+600+300")
        self.lbContactInfoOrInAboutApp = tk.Label(self.windowContactInfo, justify = "left", text = "ФИО:\nБредун Денис Сергеевич\nНомера телефонов:\n0636515388 - Telegram, Viber\n0995354808 - Telegram", bg = "black", fg = "white", font = "Arial 14")
        self.lbContactInfoOrInAboutApp.place(x = 1, y = 1)
        
    def openChildWindow(self, event):
        if self.windowInfoAboutApp != None:
            self.windowInfoAboutApp.destroy()
        if self.windowContactInfo != None:
            self.windowContactInfo.destroy()
        if self.root.childWindow != None:
            self.root.childWindow.destroy()
        self.root.childWindow = tk.Toplevel(self.root, highlightthickness = 0, bd = 0)
        self.root.childWindow.title("Список просмотренных мною аниме")
        self.root.childWindow.resizable(False, False)
        self.root.childWindow["background"] = "black"
        self.listOfAnimes = ["Город, в котором меня нет", "Эхо террора", "Приоритет Чудо-Яйца", "Берсерк", "Союз серокрылых", "Нет игры - нет жизни", "Мастера меча онлайн", "Тетрадь смерти", "Фальшивая любовь", "Врата Штейна (все сезоны)", "Цикл историй", "Удзаки хочет тусоваться!", "Ушастые друзья", "Oregairu", "Моя заботливая 800-летняя жена", "Песнь ночных сов", "Вайолет Эвергарден", "Человек-бензопила", "Добро пожаловать в класс превосходства", "Призрак в доспехах"]
        self.listOfAnimes_var = tk.Variable(value=self.listOfAnimes)
        self.listOfAnimesElement = tk.Listbox(self.root.childWindow, listvariable = self.listOfAnimes_var, font = "Arial 16", bg = "black", fg = "white", selectbackground = "white", selectmode = "single", selectforeground = "red")
        self.root.childWindow.geometry("450x255+600+300")
        self.listOfAnimesElement.pack(fill="x")
        scroll = tk.Scrollbar(self.listOfAnimesElement, command=self.listOfAnimesElement.yview)
        scroll.place(x = 430, height = 250)
        self.listOfAnimesElement.config(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)

    def callback(self, url):
        webbrowser.open_new(url)
    
    def on_checked(self, cvar):
        if cvar.get() == 1:
            self.checker = True
            if len(self.links) == 0:
                lb1 = tk.Label(self.root, text = "Описание", bg = "black", fg = "cyan", font = "Arial 18", cursor="hand2")
                lb1.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: self.callback("https://jut-su.net/91-van-pis-f1.html"))
                lb2 = tk.Label(self.root, text = "Описание", bg = "black", fg = "cyan", font = "Arial 18", cursor="hand2")
                lb2.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: self.callback("https://jut-su.net/45-moja-gerojskaja-akademija.html"))
                lb3 = tk.Label(self.root, text = "Описание", bg = "black", fg = "cyan", font = "Arial 18", cursor="hand2")
                lb3.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: self.callback("https://jut-su.net/231-jetot-zamechatelnyj-mir-s1.html"))
                lb4 = tk.Label(self.root, text = "Описание", bg = "black", fg = "cyan", font = "Arial 18", cursor="hand2")
                lb4.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: self.callback("https://jut-su.net/454-neobjatnyj-okean.html"))
                lb5 = tk.Label(self.root, text = "Описание", bg = "black", fg = "cyan", font = "Arial 18", cursor="hand2")
                lb5.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: self.callback("https://jut-su.net/1185-moja-devushka-sovsem-ne-milaja-y1.html"))
                lb6 = tk.Label(self.root, text = "Описание", bg = "black", fg = "cyan", font = "Arial 18", cursor="hand2")
                lb6.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: self.callback("https://jut-su.net/124-udzaki-hochet-tusovatsja.html"))
                lb7 = tk.Label(self.root, text = "Описание", bg = "black", fg = "cyan", font = "Arial 18", cursor="hand2")
                lb7.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: self.callback("https://jut-su.net/724-dobro-pozhalovat-v-klass-prevoshodstva.html"))
                lb8 = tk.Label(self.root, text = "Описание", bg = "black", fg = "cyan", font = "Arial 18", cursor="hand2")
                lb8.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: self.callback("https://jut-su.net/99-obeschannyj-neverlend.html"))
                lb9 = tk.Label(self.root, text = "Описание", bg = "black", fg = "cyan", font = "Arial 18", cursor="hand2")
                lb9.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: self.callback("https://jut-su.net/1069-prioritet-chudo-jajca.html"))
                lb10 = tk.Label(self.root, text = "Описание", bg = "black", fg = "cyan", font = "Arial 18", cursor="hand2")
                lb10.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: self.callback("https://jut-su.net/1026-jeho-terrora.html"))
                self.links = {
                    "Сёнэн": [lb1, lb2],
                    "Комедия": [lb3, lb4],
                    "Повседневность": [lb5, lb6],
                    "Психология": [lb7, lb8],
                    "Триллер": [lb9, lb10]
                    }
            self.showLinksOnThePage()
        else:
            self.checker = False
            self.deleteActiveLinks()

    def showLinksOnThePage(self):
        if self.clickedButton == "Сёнэн":
            self.links[self.clickedButton][0].place(x = 150, y = 410)
            self.links[self.clickedButton][1].place(x = 885, y = 480)
        elif self.clickedButton == "Комедия":
            self.links[self.clickedButton][0].place(x = 140, y = 315)
            self.links[self.clickedButton][1].place(x = 840, y = 315)
        elif self.clickedButton == "Повседневность":
            self.links[self.clickedButton][0].place(x = 185, y = 460)
            self.links[self.clickedButton][1].place(x = 870, y = 480)
        elif self.clickedButton == "Психология":
            self.links[self.clickedButton][0].place(x = 160, y = 480)
            self.links[self.clickedButton][1].place(x = 850, y = 420)
        else:
            self.links[self.clickedButton][0].place(x = 170, y = 480)
            self.links[self.clickedButton][1].place(x = 863, y = 470)
        self.activeLinks = self.links[self.clickedButton]

    def deleteActiveLinks(self):
        for x in self.activeLinks:
            x.place(x = 9999999, y = 9999999)

    def is_valid(self, newval):
        return newval == "" or (newval != " " and newval.isdigit() and len(newval) <= 100 and int(newval) <= 100 and int(newval) > 0)

    def printDependingOnAge(self):
        if self.constantAge == None:
            if self.printedAge.get().isdigit():
                age = int(self.printedAge.get())
                if self.ageLabel != None:
                    self.ageLabel.place(x = 9999999, y = 9999999)
            else:
                self.ageLabel = tk.Label(self.root, text = "Введите возраст!!!", font = "Arial 13", bg = "black", fg = "white")
                self.ageLabel.place(x = 490, y = 240)
                return 0
            if age <= 7:
                self.ageLabel = tk.Label(self.root, text = "Тебе мало лет для подобного рода аниме.", font = "Arial 13", bg = "black", fg = "white")
                self.ageLabel.place(x = 400, y = 240)
            elif age >= 75:
                self.ageLabel = tk.Label(self.root, text = "Здоровья вам!=)", font = "Arial 13", bg = "black", fg = "white")
                self.ageLabel.place(x = 480, y = 240)
            else:
                self.ageLabel = tk.Label(self.root, text = 'Смотрели аниме "Берсерк"?', font = "Arial 13", bg = "black", fg = "white")
                self.ageLabel.place(x = 450, y = 240)
                r_var = tk.IntVar()
                r_var.set(0)
                r1 = tk.Radiobutton(self.root, font = "Arial 13", disabledforeground = "green", text='Да', command = lambda r_var = r_var: self.checkIfUserWatchedBerserk(r_var), variable=r_var, value=1, activeforeground = "green", activebackground = "black", bg = "black", fg = "green")
                r2 = tk.Radiobutton(self.root, font = "Arial 13", disabledforeground = "red", text='Нет', command = lambda r_var = r_var: self.checkIfUserWatchedBerserk(r_var), variable=r_var, value=2, activeforeground = "red", activebackground = "black", bg = "black", fg = "red")
                r1.place(x = 510, y = 270)
                r2.place(x = 570, y = 270)
                self.myRadioButtons = [r1, r2]
            self.constantAge = int(self.printedAge.get())

    def checkIfUserWatchedBerserk(self, r_var):
        answer = int(r_var.get())
        if answer == 1:
            im = Image.open("dicaprio.png")
            kh = im.height/350
            im = im.resize((round(im.width/kh), round(im.height/kh)), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
            im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
            lb = tk.Label(self.root, image = im, bd = 0)
            lb.image = im
            lb.place(x = 400, y = 320)
        elif answer == 2:
            im = Image.open("bladerunner.png")
            kh = im.width/350
            im = im.resize((round(im.width/kh), round(im.height/kh)), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
            im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
            lb = tk.Label(self.root, image = im, bd = 0)
            lb.image = im
            lb.place(x = 400, y = 320)
        self.myRadioButtons[0]["state"] = "disabled"
        self.myRadioButtons[1]["state"] = "disabled"

    def sendDataAboutAge(self, event):
        self.mySendAgeButton.invoke()
    
    def printInfoAboutAnime(self, text):
        self.clickedButton = text
        if self.checkbutton == None:
            cvar = tk.IntVar()
            cvar.set(0)
            self.checkbutton = tk.Checkbutton(self.root, activeforeground = "green", activebackground = "black", bg = "black", fg = "green", text="Ссылки на описания", variable=cvar, command = lambda cvar = cvar: self.on_checked(cvar), font = "Arial 18")
            self.checkbutton.place(x = 430, y = 140)
            self.printedAge = tk.StringVar()
            check = (self.root.register(self.is_valid), "%P")
            self.myTextField = tk.Entry(self.root.frames[1], width=3, validate="key", validatecommand=check, textvariable = self.printedAge, highlightthickness = 0, bd = 0, font = "Arial 15")
            self.myTextField.bind('<Return>', self.sendDataAboutAge)
            self.myTextField.pack(side="left")
            self.mySendAgeButton = tk.Button(self.root.frames[1], text = "Отправить", height = 1, width = 16, bg = "black", fg = "white",\
            font = "Arial 10", relief = "groove", overrelief = "sunken", command = self.printDependingOnAge)
            self.mySendAgeButton.pack(side="left")
            self.root.frames[1].place(x = 480, y = 180)
        
        if self.checker == True:
            self.deleteActiveLinks()
            self.showLinksOnThePage()
        
        self.chooseWhat2LabelsToPrint(text)
        self.chooseWhat2ImagesToPrint(text)

    def chooseWhat2LabelsToPrint(self, text):
        if len(self.showedElementsByClickingButtom) == 0:
            self.print2Labels(text)
        else:
            for x in self.activeElements["labels"]:
                x.place(x = 9999999, y = 999999)
            try:
                for x in self.activeElements["images"]:
                    x.place(x = 9999999, y = 999999)
            except:
                pass
            allGenres = list(self.showedElementsByClickingButtom.keys())
            for x in allGenres:
                if x == text:
                    if text == "Сёнэн":
                        self.showedElementsByClickingButtom[text]["labels"][0].place(x = 175, y = 75)
                        self.showedElementsByClickingButtom[text]["labels"][1].place(x = 800, y = 75)
                    elif text == "Комедия":
                        self.showedElementsByClickingButtom[text]["labels"][0].place(x = 150, y = 75)
                        self.showedElementsByClickingButtom[text]["labels"][1].place(x = 800, y = 75)
                    elif text == "Повседневность":
                        self.showedElementsByClickingButtom[text]["labels"][0].place(x = 75, y = 75)
                        self.showedElementsByClickingButtom[text]["labels"][1].place(x = 783, y = 75)
                    elif text == "Психология":
                        self.showedElementsByClickingButtom[text]["labels"][0].place(x = 0, y = 75)
                        self.showedElementsByClickingButtom[text]["labels"][1].place(x = 765, y = 75)
                    else:
                        self.showedElementsByClickingButtom[text]["labels"][0].place(x = 110, y = 75)
                        self.showedElementsByClickingButtom[text]["labels"][1].place(x = 845, y = 75)
                    self.activeElements = self.showedElementsByClickingButtom[text]
                    return 0
            self.print2Labels(text)

    def print2Labels(self, text):
        if text == "Сёнэн":
            text1 = "Ван Пис"
            text2 = "Моя геройская академия"
            lb1 = tk.Label(self.root, text = text1, bg = "black", fg = "white", font = "Arial 18")
            lb2 = tk.Label(self.root, text = text2, bg = "black", fg = "white", font = "Arial 18")
            lb1.place(x = 175, y = 75)
            lb2.place(x = 800, y = 75)
        elif text == "Комедия":
            text1 = "Коносуба"
            text2 = "Необъятый океан"
            lb1 = tk.Label(self.root, text = text1, bg = "black", fg = "white", font = "Arial 18")
            lb2 = tk.Label(self.root, text = text2, bg = "black", fg = "white", font = "Arial 18")
            lb1.place(x = 150, y = 75)
            lb2.place(x = 800, y = 75)
        elif text == "Повседневность":
            text1 = "Моя девушка не только милая"
            text2 = "Удзаки хочет тусоваться!"
            lb1 = tk.Label(self.root, text = text1, bg = "black", fg = "white", font = "Arial 18")
            lb2 = tk.Label(self.root, text = text2, bg = "black", fg = "white", font = "Arial 18")
            lb1.place(x = 75, y = 75)
            lb2.place(x = 783, y = 75)
        elif text == "Психология":
            text1 = "Добро пожаловать в класс превосходства"
            text2 = "Обещанный Неверленд"
            lb1 = tk.Label(self.root, text = text1, bg = "black", fg = "white", font = "Arial 18")
            lb2 = tk.Label(self.root, text = text2, bg = "black", fg = "white", font = "Arial 18")
            lb1.place(x = 0, y = 75)
            lb2.place(x = 765, y = 75)
        else:
            text1 = "Приоритет Чудо-Яйца"
            text2 = "Эхо Террора"
            lb1 = tk.Label(self.root, text = text1, bg = "black", fg = "white", font = "Arial 18")
            lb2 = tk.Label(self.root, text = text2, bg = "black", fg = "white", font = "Arial 18")
            lb1.place(x = 110, y = 75)
            lb2.place(x = 845, y = 75)

        self.showedElementsByClickingButtom.update({text:{"labels": [lb1, lb2]}})
        self.activeElements = self.showedElementsByClickingButtom[text]
    
    def chooseWhat2ImagesToPrint(self, text):
        if text == "Сёнэн":
            file1 = "Сёнэн/One_Piece.png"
            file2 = "Сёнэн/My_Hero_Academia.png"
        elif text == "Комедия":
            file1 = "Комедия/Konosuba.png"
            file2 = "Комедия/grand_blue.png"
        elif text == "Повседневность":
            file1 = "Повседневность/cute.png"
            file2 = "Повседневность/Udzaki.png"
        elif text == "Психология":
            file1 = "Психология/class.png"
            file2 = "Психология/promised_neverland.png"
        else:
            file1 = "Триллер/wondereggpriority.png"
            file2 = "Триллер/Zankyou_no_Terror.png"

        try:
            allGenres = list(self.showedElementsByClickingButtom.keys())
            for x in allGenres:
                if x == text:
                    self.showedElementsByClickingButtom[text]["images"][0].place(x = 110, y = 120)
                    self.showedElementsByClickingButtom[text]["images"][1].place(x = 800, y = 120)
                    self.activeElements = self.showedElementsByClickingButtom[text]
                    return 0
        except:
            self.print2Images(text, file1, file2, 110, 120, 800, 120)

    def print2Images(self, text, file1, file2, x1, y1, x2, y2):
        image1 = Image.open(file1)
        if image1.height > 350:
            kh = image1.height/350
            image1 = image1.resize((round(image1.width/kh), round(image1.height/kh)), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
        image2 = Image.open(file2)
        if image2.height > 350:
            kh = image2.height/350
            image2 = image2.resize((round(image2.width/kh), round(image2.height/kh)), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
        image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image1)
        image2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image2)
        lb1 = tk.Label(self.root, image = image1, bd = 0)
        lb2 = tk.Label(self.root, image = image2, bd = 0)
        lb1.image = image1
        lb2.image = image2
        lb1.place(x = x1, y = y1)
        lb2.place(x = x2, y = y2)
        allGenres = list(self.showedElementsByClickingButtom.keys())
        for x in allGenres:
            if x == text:
                self.showedElementsByClickingButtom[text].update({"images":[lb1, lb2]})
                self.activeElements = self.showedElementsByClickingButtom[text]
                return 0
        self.showedElementsByClickingButtom.update({text:{"images": [lb1, lb2]}})
        self.activeElements = self.showedElementsByClickingButtom[text]

running = True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while running:
        app = App()
        app.startApp()
```